# when updating location.hash in Chrome the jQuery animation "freezes" for a second

Tags: jquery, hash, google-chrome, jquery-animate

I'm trying to create a sort of "virtual gallery". I'm using Coda Slider 2.0 & jQuery v1.4.2

It behaves perfectly in IE, FF & Safari, but Chrome seems to reload/hang for a second when setting location.hash. This causes the jQuery animation to freeze for a second :S

Example: http://hardyernst.dk/gallery.html try clicking on the navigation links above the pictures.

The jQuery code that is being executed when clicking a navigation link:

```
        $('#coda-nav-' + sliderCount + ' a').each(function(z) {
        // What happens when a nav link is clicked
        $(this).bind("click", function() {
            offset = -(panelWidth*z);
            navClicks++;
            $(this).addClass('current').parents('ul').find('a').not($(this)).removeClass('current');
            alterPanelHeight(z);
            currentPanel = z + 1;
            $('.panel-container', slider).stop().animate({ left: offset }, settings.slideEaseDuration, settings.slideEaseFunction, function(){
            if (!settings.crossLinking) { return false; } // Don't change the URL hash unless cross-linking is specified
            });
        });
    });
```

if I add

```
return false;
```

at the end of the function. The animation will slide *smoothly :)*... **BUT** as you might have guessed the location.hash value remains unchanged :(

I have tried setting the location.hash earlier in the function alas it did not change the behavior in Chrome

Would be immensely grateful for any help :)

**Regards Ubunut**

**edit:**
So now i moved location.hash into the animation callback, it's a lot smoother :) but if you click two nav-links rapidly after each other the animation will hang/freeze momentarily (just like before). I could add a jQuery .delay() but i'd rather not do it that way. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have not put this as an answer, becuase it does't solve your problem using jQuery.  But this is almost entirely possible in CSS3  using -webkit-transition (and the moz version) and the CSS3 selector :target - obviously jQuery works in all browsers at the moment.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the effort & I will look into it! :)
Since this is only an issue with Chrome I can still use jQuery in IE & FF, -moz-transition has yet to be implemented :(

Comment: hmm... On second thought the method you describe would still change the location.hash value, causing Chrome to reload(or whatever it's doing) will this not affect the CSS3 transition too? (causing it to "pause" like with .animate() )

Comment: You can try to use Profiler and Timeline from Chrome DevTools for troubleshoot this problem.

Comment: @loislo I've tried but this seems to be a problem with Chrome. Look at  flavors.me/caseypugh every time you change the location.hash Chrome will lock up for a split second. Causing the javascript animation to pause :/